# Angular ui router match any route get all query parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-routing

With angular ui router I simply want to match any url and get all query parameters from that url, how do I do this?

Say I navigate to this url: `?name=Julian&lastName=Krispel`

I expect the router to resolve this url into the following parameters:

```
{
    name: 'Julian',
    lastName: 'Krispel'
}
```

How would I do this, is this something that I have to implement manually or is this something that angular ui does? I can't find anything on google or in the docs that seems to solve this problem.

Comment: Could you please post some sample code. Are you using ngRoute or ui-router (from the angular-ui project). At what point do you need these parameters? There are many places where you can extract them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the $stateParams service in your controller, but having said that you also need to have the proper routing setup to grab the params with ui-router.

[RTFM](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) in the nicest possible way of course! :-)